# Bootstrap 4 Navbar doesnt collapse in Angular4

Tags: css, angular, navbar, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I'm working with Bootstrap 4 and Ng-Bootstrap in an Angular 4 Project,

i have linked the que bootstrap.css in my angular-cli.json this way

```
 "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```

and imported the NgbModule in my app.module that looks like this

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

i made a Navbar copying the documentation from the bootstrap website and added the toggle component from ng-bootstrap (it works well) the code looks like this

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-
target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-
expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
          <div class="nav-link" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle 
dropdown</div>
          <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
            <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
            <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
            <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" 
aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" 
type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

the problem starts when i scale down the window and the toggle does its work, when i press the button for collapsing the navbar it doesn't work.

i tried installing and linking the js files of jquery and popper and the bootstrap one, but it still doesn't work, the actual angular-cli.json looks like this

```
     "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"

      ],
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To work with angular you need this fix

first define this in your class `public navbarCollapsed = true;`

then chnage your button

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" (click)="navbarCollapsed = !navbarCollapsed" [attr.aria-expanded]="!navbarCollapsed" aria-controls="navbarContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

also you need to add this to your collapsing div

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" [ngbCollapse]="navbarCollapsed" id="navbarSupportedContent">
```

now you don't need jquery, popper or bootstrap.js

you can find more info about this issue [here](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/738).

also check ng-bootstraps working demo page code [link](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/5886946c28597a584c196671bc54053cb06d3459/demo/src/app/app.component.html#L2-L41).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I used normal bootstrap 4 rather then ng-bootstrap and this way I don't need to any module in app.module file as well. it works. Below is the script add into angular.json (angular v6) and bootstrap 4+:

```js
"scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
            "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js", 
             "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"]
```

For CSS I prefer to use Scss version so it goes like this.

```js
"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss"
            ],
```

and i import bootstrap into style.scss file

```js
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

Cheers! 
JK

Answer (score 0):

Look for the compiled classes, maybe you get the wrong version. I had a similar issue with the class col-sm-offset-#, the problem was that this classes doesn't exist in that version. Maybe could be the same issue

This is the route ..\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js here we have two file 
bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js

find into bootstrap.js the nav classes. if you could not found it, look for another Bootstrap repository.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me
I installed
`npm i  --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap ng add @angular/localize`

- app.module.ts

`import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';`

`imports:[NgbModule]`

NgbModule.forRoot() not working

- angular.json
  `"styles": [ "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "src/styles.css" ],` "scripts": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js]`

Hope this helps, even just alittle bit